# How to collect a collection of objects that are contained in the current month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Provided that. That we have an object that the date field contains for itself, like a date: "2019-09-24"

```
#<Assignment id: 57, date: "2019-09-24">
```

And having such information, we see that this date refers to September, I need to find all the objects that exist in the range of days from the first to the last of September.

```
Assignment.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', "2019-09-01", "2019-09-30")
```

works fine, but i dont know how to find all dates :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have an assignment where to take the `date` from, you can get the first and last day of that month:

```
assigment_date = assignment.date.to_date
Assignment.where(date: assignment_date.beginning_of_month..assignment_date.end_of_month)
```